# How to count numbers for each group?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say there is a result set...I need to print it out like so:

```
ID  Count
1    5
1    5 
1    5
1    5
1    5
2    2
2    2
3    1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tag with your version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean that your query:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM tableX
GROUP BY ID ;
```

produces this:

```
ID  Count
1    5
2    2
3    1
```

but you want this?:

```
ID  Count
1    5
1    5 
1    5
1    5
1    5
2    2
2    2
3    1
```

Then, this query will do:

```
SELECT grp.ID, grp."Count"
FROM 
        tableX AS t
    JOIN
        ( SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS "Count"
          FROM tableX
          GROUP BY ID 
        ) AS grp
      ON grp.ID = t.ID ;
```

It will work in almost all DBMS and in all versions of SQL-Server. For SQL-Server versions 2005 and newer (and also in Oracle and Postgres), the answer with the `OVER` clause looks more elegant and may be prefered. Test in your version which one is more efficient. I think that in 2012 version, queries with `OVER` clause are quite efficient.

Comment: You said "the answer with the OVER clause is better." But in my experience, those windowing functions can be huge performance drains. There are times when queries became very slow when I used `Count() OVER` and became fast again when I just did the pedestrian join to an aggregate subquery, exactly like here.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `count()` with **[`OVER` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)**:

```
select a, count(*) over (partition by a) as [count]
from tableName ;
```

It's called window function. I recommend you study these.

Comment: Oops, I hadn't noticed the [tag:SQL-Server] tag. This is much better and simpler than my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I started answer in this site. and this is very much fun.  it's also improve my English

Comment: @ypercube - But it doesn't say `SQL Server 2005+`. Your answer is correct, don't know if you should've deleted it